# How to access in code the NSNumberFormatter properties in a NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have created a nib file with a normal IBOulet for a `NSTextField`.
In IB (4.4), add a `NSNumberFormatter` for this `NSTextField` and give this some properties, like Decimal Style, max and min values, etc.

Now, I want to modify in code, some other properties for this `NSNumberFormatter` already embedded in the textfield, like SetGroupingSeparator, SetMaximunFractionDigits etc.

Let say my `NSTextField` is named pf,
normally I can access the value (string) in the cell as:

```
[pf SetFloatValue]
```

or

```
myFloat = [pf floatValue].
```

That is working without any problems.
However, I have been unable to find in the documentation or anywhere an example how to modify the `NSNumberFormatter` properties in code.
I know how to create a `NSNumberFormatter` in code, but do not know how to assign it to the `NSTextField` (which I don't know if will overrides the one create in IB).
Could anyone help me with a clear example how to do this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create and set a NSNumberFormatter to a NSTextField in code can be done via:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[[textField cell] setFormatter:numberFormatter];
```

The details for which I found in [Apple's Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfCells.html)

Modifying a formatter should be pretty similiar, accessing the formatter via [`[NSCell formatter]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCell/formatter):

```
NSNumberFormatter * numberFormatter = [[textField cell] formatter];
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. That works and save me a good time continuing searching.

Answer (score 0):

You do it just like any other object in IB.  Create an IBOutlet for the formatter in your .h file and connect it to the formatter in IB, then you can access its properties through the outlet.

Comment: Thanks rdelmar. I will try this approach too.